# SQLite DB problem when we use different accounts in single app with same device

Tags: android, sqlite

It's not a code problem but it's just by my curiosity.
I am making an application that can be logged in by social login, and also email login. 
In my application, I plan to use some SQLiteDatabase to save simple datas.
However, when I just save it with A account and login with different account, won't there be conflict because its the same device and server is not intervened with it? How do you know it's different account when its the same device, one application?

Think its sort of a silly question maybe, but if there's a way that everyone uses to solve it, I would like to know.

Comment: Create the db files based on the username.

Comment: you need some kind of user ID or account ID, so you hsave the data with specific account ID, and then you can differentiate between different accounts' data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two cases -

1. You want to use same database for different users -

In this case, there is no problem as your SQLite database gets saved in your app's `/data/data` folder which will be always accessible from inside your app.

2. You want to use different database for different users -

In this case, you have to add user_id column in all the tables of your SQLite database, and based on your `user_ids`, you can do your database actions like query, deletion, etc